# Are backbone models and collections expected to have the same item representation?

Tags: web-services, rest, backbone.js, api-design

Suppose we have a rest API to get back some items located at /items which returns a JSON array like so

```
[ {....},{...},{...} .... {...}]
```

suppose that items/{id} returns the representation of the item with id {id}

to get to item 4 it is possible to do it in two ways:

**Case 1:** get /items and then search the response for an item with id #4

**Case 2:** get /item/4

should the representation to returned by case 1 be identical as the representation returned by case 2?

**EDIT 1** for example /dogs could return an array of dog resources where only the name and the id are populated and /dogs/4 could return full details for a dog resource.

Comment: What is the alternative? That is, why should it not be identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

You can return different structures from Collection and from Model.

#### Long answer

You can return in your JSON whatever you want, Backbone will build an entity of your `Model` using the data provided by the JSON, Backbone will adapt the created instance to the data provided, merging it with the declared `Model.defaults`.

You can even, for example, return different JSON structure for this two queries:

- /dogs/1
- /dogs/2

I understand your concern, you are trying to `fetch` a bunch of objects with very low data detail and then `fetch` the full data for a concrete instance when is needed.

I don't see any problem on it.

Try to *mark* your *uncompleted* Models to not using them in the detailing Views without fetching the whole data.